# Use 'R' to plot two lines on the same graph

Tags: r

With this approach.  I have a line plot graph.  I want to plot 'two' line plot on the same graph.   How can I simply add that data,

The data is in the form

```
1  5  10
2  8  20
3  9  30
```

I want to plot the X as column1 and the other two columns along the y axis.

```
-----
 # Commands
  2
  3 library(ggplot2)
  4
  5 req <- read.table("stats_quick_sort.dat")
  6
  7 summary(req)
  8
  9 xx <- req$V1
 10 yy <- req$V2
 11
 12
 13 png('stats_sort_image.png', width=800, height=600)
 14 gg <- qplot(xx, yy) + geom_line()
 15 print(gg)
 16 dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside -- if you provide a *reproducible* example that demonstrates your problem, it is much easier for us to help you. I'm going to give you a reproducible example as an answer so you see what I mean. It means anyone can copy and paste the code and it'll work (whereas I couldn't copy/paste your code because I don't have `stats_quick_sort.dat`).

To plot multiple lines on a plot you just call `geom_line` again, feeding in the `x` and `y` variables to `aes`:

```
# generate some dummy data so this example can be reproduced
xx  <- sort(runif(20))
yy  <- runif(20)
yy2 <- runif(20)

gg <- qplot(xx, yy) + geom_line()        # first line
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes( x=xx, y=yy2 )) # add the second line!
print(gg)
```

In general, if you want to add other information to your plot that you did not supply in the initial `qplot`/`ggplot` call, then just feed it in to `aes`. You want a line? Use `geom_line`. You want new x and y coordinates? Then use `geom_line(aes(x= .., y=..))`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a *slightly* more canonical way to use ggplot is to create a long data.frame and map each variable of interest to an aesthetic. This provides an easy way to add legends automagically, etc. This also scales easier than adding individual layers each time you want a new line. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#Thanks mathematical coffee for data
dat <- data.frame(xx  = sort(runif(20))
                  , yy  = runif(20)
                  , yy2 = runif(20))

#Melt into long format, using xx as the ID variable
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "xx")

#What does this look like now?
> head(dat.m,3)
           xx variable     value
1 0.001895333       yy 0.1240757
2 0.037347893       yy 0.8760621
3 0.086915655       yy 0.4068837

#use ggplot and set the group and colour aesthetic to the variable column. This adds a legend
ggplot(dat.m, aes(xx, value, group = variable, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Can I do more than two Y plots?  Three or four?

Comment: @berlinbrown2 - absolutely. That's where the `melt` function comes in really handy. Given a data.frame of 6 columns with 1 x-variable and 5 y-variables, the function `melt(yourData, id.vars = "x")` will create the appropriate long data.frame. The ggplot website has a ton of good examples that you can check out: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/. I should warn/note that ggplot2 0.9.0 was a pretty big rewrite and I'm not sure if all of the examples have been updated *yet*.